# How to prevent ArrowDown when reached bottom in react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

In react-select,

When press ArrowDown on last option, focus is going to first option.
And press ArrowUp on first option, focus is going to last option.

How to prevent it?
Should I make my own `MenuList` for this?

I really want to prevent only this behavior because I will fetch more options from server when focus reached last option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API in the [docs](https://react-select.com/props) to do such thing I'm afraid. One possible solution is to:

- Keep track of your current focus index by listening to `focus` event.
- Intercept `keydown` event and stop the keystroke conditionally based on the current focus index and `options.length`. *Note* that `keydown` event fires before `focus` event.

```js
export function MySelect() {
  const focusIndexRef = useRef(-1);

  return (
    <Select
      options={options}
      ariaLiveMessages={{
        onFocus: (e) => {
          focusIndexRef.current = e.options.indexOf(e.focused);
        }
      }}
      onKeyDown={(e) => {
        if (e.key === "ArrowDown" && focusIndexRef.current === options.length - 1) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (e.key === "ArrowUp" && focusIndexRef.current === 0) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66962934/how-to-prevent-arrowdown-when-reached-bottom-in-react-select]